# Best way to display table data and download files

Tags: php, html, mysql, download

Through my webpage I am uploading **wav** files to the server using move_uploaded_file filesystem function, the details of the file such as **name of a file**, and **file path** is getting stored in a table called **files**.

Now i want to display the uploaded files and download them by clicking on a hyperlink. I've tried to do it somehow like this:

```
    <?php
    ...
    while ($records = mysql_fetch_array($getFilesByID)){?>

    <ul>
    <li><a href=<?php echo $records['FILE_PATH'];?>><?php echo $records['NAME'];?></a></li>
    </ul>

    <?php }?>
    ...
```

And this worked for the display but I'm still far from downloading those files. What would be the best approach to do this display->download files scenario?!

As you can judge from the question itself, I am a beginner so I need some guidance here.

Thanks

Comment: what happens when you click the link? Is there any error in the console?

Comment: i think you have to mention the file name at the end of the file path

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. File path contains the file name, that is not the issue, but I just find out that I had a mistake in the file name. I was getting 404(NOT FOUND) error.

Comment: I think that my issue is now solved and your questions helped a lot!!!